# Correctly Applying Pivot Functions

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have this dataset:

```
my_data = structure(list(col = c("A", "B", "C"), `2000-01-01` = c(86L, 
43L, 73L), `2000-01-02` = c(99L, 77L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

  col 2000-01-01 2000-01-02
1   A         86         99
2   B         43         77
3   C         73         12
```

My goal is to transform this dataset into the following format:

```
        date col count
1 2000-01-01   A    86
2 2000-01-01   B    43
3 2000-01-01   C    73
4 2000-01-02   A    99
5 2000-01-02   B    77
6 2000-01-02   C    12
```

**Have I done this correctly?**

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyr)
# how come this seems to works for all columns even though I only specified "2001-01-01"?
my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(!col, names_to = "2001-01-01", values_to = "count")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  col   `2001-01-01` count
  <chr> <chr>        <int>
1 A     2000-01-01      86
2 A     2000-01-02      99
3 B     2000-01-01      43
4 B     2000-01-02      77
5 C     2000-01-01      73
6 C     2000-01-02      12
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just change `names_to = "2001-01-01"` to `names_to = "date"` to get the correct naming. More of a personal taste, I would use `-` to indicate not, or subtract from, rather than `!`. Mainly, because as you advance in programing you might start unquoting statements with `!!`. In my mind, it is also more direct to think everything minus this (what ever this is). Than not this (again what ever it is). But clearly they are saying the same thing.

Comment: @ Baraliuh: thank you so much for your reply! I tried your code:

Comment: my_data %>%     pivot_longer(!col, names_to = "date", values_to = "count")

Comment: Also, not that to get the exact thing you want you also need to sort:
`pivot_longer(...) %>% arrange(date)` or replace date with ``2001-01-01``

Comment: And I got the following error: Error in `chr_as_locations()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `col` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Like this? my_data %>% arrange(date) %>%
    pivot_longer(!col, names_to = "DATE", values_to = "count")

Comment: @stats_noob, `names_to=` has no bearing on what columns are pivoting, it is only used for naming the columns that are created (from a combination of many others). Specifying `"2000-01-01"` is completely separate from the fact that `"2000-01-01"` is present in the data; `pivot_*` doesn't look for that condition and doesn't care. If you do just `pivot_longer(my_data, -col)` you'll see that it uses the default `names_to="name"`, which is never present in the original data _anywhere_.

Comment: I think there is a possible confusion between `names_to` (described by @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY) and `names_from` which is used in `pivot_wider` to indicate what column(s) you want to become many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done it like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
structure(list(col = c("A", "B", "C"), `2000-01-01` = c(86L, 
                                                        43L, 73L), `2000-01-02` = c(99L, 77L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                         -3L)
    ) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-col, names_to = 'date', values_to = 'count') %>% 
    arrange(date, col)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   col   date       count
#>   <chr> <chr>      <int>
#> 1 A     2000-01-01    86
#> 2 B     2000-01-01    43
#> 3 C     2000-01-01    73
#> 4 A     2000-01-02    99
#> 5 B     2000-01-02    77
#> 6 C     2000-01-02    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your answer! Just to clarify - my original code was correct, just not efficient - yes? Thank you so much!

Comment: You were just missing a bit on the naming of one of the new columns. In terms of efficiency it was just fine. But in  terms of syntax I think `-` can be superior to `!` in certain circumstances.

Comment: Ah, yes. Boolean logic to the rescue.